# Don't Duplicate Entries Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently calling this every 3hrs, but it's storing duplicates of the same data. I've tried a few methods here on Stackoverflow but none of them seem to be actually working.

```
  def fetch_data

    response = self.class.get("/tap-2_JD7rkZupwNmg91im5G/last_ready_run/data?format=json")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["link"]

    # To access the image src's:
    image_srcs = @elements.collect { |e| e['image'] }

    image_srcs.each do |image|
      self.entries.create(image: image)
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to check against each 'image' string that it collects and make sure it's not a duplicate before it inserts a new entry into the database

Thanks

**Edit - Example Response**

```
{
  "link": [
    {
      "link": "http://www.test.com",
      "image": "http://www.test.com/500x500.jpg"
    }, ....
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on what's in `element` hash?
Are you sure there won't be different items with the same `image`?
Is `validates :image, uniqueness: true` working for you?

Comment: I've added an example of the response, trying to make sure that images are unique within the database and duplicates can't be added

Comment: Ah validates image and uniqueness worked - but I forgot to put it on my entries model! Apologies - post it as an answer and I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rails build-in validation: `validate :image, :uniqueness`. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Note: beware that it's not 100% protection from duplicates. For more robust solution please use DB level constraints (ex. `add_index :entries, :image, unique: true` in migrations)